# I seem to only suffer gastro-intestinal issues when I drink a particular beer. That being Founders All Day IPA Session Ale. Why?

Tags: health, ipa

I love the beer.  Most folks do I suppose.  I cant be the only one that has issues with GI after only having a few of these.
I can drink other alcohol just fine. Why this one beer?

Comment: According to Founders it’s made with “a complex array of malts, grains and hops”. Perhaps one of those grains disagrees with you.

Comment: I'm sure it's not just this beer. I looked up some information on the recipe they use. The thing that stands out to me is they use 20% flaked oats, while not common it's not to unusual either. Other than that it's regular barley malt. They use a variety of hops and a standard American ale yeast. It's possible, but highly unlikely you have having a reaction to the yeast or hops or barley. My guess it's the yeast. It's the same yeast that is used with Sierra Nevada Pale Ale so give that a shot and see if it does the same thing.

Comment: @farmersteve I’m interested in how you went about getting information on the beer’s recipe. As it is, I think your comment makes a good answer.

Comment: I just did a google search on this beer and what they call a clone recipe in homebrewing circles. Homebrewers like to replicate certain recipes for commercial beers they like. Sometimes, commercial brewers even share their recipes. Just start googling. You might want to check on the oats too. Like I said, there are quite a high percentage in this recipe.

Comment: A few people get IBS from certain ales and is usually due to the type of barley the malt comes from. A friend of mine converted to lager or Guinness for a few years, then came back to beer later. However, everyone is different.